# Restrict search to siblings in Groovy XML?

Tags: xml, groovy

I have XML in the following form, which I am parsing with XmlSlurper:

```
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name="key">
        <uri>http://key/key1</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="value">
        <literal>Value 1 for key 1</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="key">
        <uri>http://key/key2</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="value">
        <literal>Value 1 for key 2</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="key">
        <uri>http://key/key1</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="value">
        <literal>Value 2 for key 1</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="key">
        <uri>http://key/key2</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="value">
        <literal>Value 2 for key 2</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
  </results>
```

Note that there are (potentially) multiple values for each key. I would like to extract essentially a MultiMap of key -> [list of values]. What is the best way for me to accomplish this? I am familiar with basic GPath constructs, and I think some form of `groupBy{}.collectEntries{}` might be appropriate, but I can't seem to get to the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that xml is stored in a String variable, `x`, one method would be to do:

```
def map = new XmlSlurper().parseText( x ).result.inject( [:].withDefault{ [] } ) { m, e ->
    m[ e.binding.uri.text() ] << e.binding.literal.text()
    m
}
```

Comment: That was definitely the correct vehicle - I had never used `inject` before. I had to do some conditional selection inside the closure, but it works great!